# How can I change default X11 application?

Tags: macos, macports, x11

I compiled my own X11 Server for Mac OS X and want it to replace the original outdated X11.app supplied by Lion. How do I do that?

Comment: How did you compile the server - ie where is its documentation?

Comment: Actually I installed the MacPorts xorg-server-devel package.

Answer (score 5):

1. cd to /usr/X11/bin
2. rename the existing X symlink to Xquartz (to X_orig for example) in case you need to revert in the future to the "vanilla" config
3. symlink X to your compiled binary.

Comment: I'd like to replace the original X11.app with my own build.

Comment: By symlinking X from /usr/X11/bin/X to your compiled binary, you're already using your compiled binary. Not sure if I'd recommend rm instead of mv the original X.

Answer (score 2):

The [XQuartz install docs](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.0) have an alternate approach for installing their X11 binary. They use launchctl and set the DISPLAY to point to the socket for their server. I believe the program it runs (launchd_startx) listens on the socket and starts the X server when a connection is made. The nice thing about this approach is it leaves the original X11.app unmodified.